# SwiftUI @EnvironmentObject error: may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, ios13

my first view can get all the data from API request, then opened second view to change the API request data, it crashed.

below is the error

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type NetworkManager found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for NetworkManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.3/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55
2019-11-07 12:00:01.961425-0800 EarthQuake[73703:5913116] Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type NetworkManager found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for NetworkManager may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros_Sim/Monoceros-39.3/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55
```

This is swift file to fetch data from API, then save data to posts

```
import Foundation
import Combine

final class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var posts = [Post]()


    func fetchData() {

         //some code to fetch data, then save to posts

    }

}
```

**In my first list view file: EarthQuakeList.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct EarthQuakeList: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager

    //@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List(networkManager.posts) { post in
                NavigationLink(destination: EarthQuakeDetail(detail: post.properties, location: post.locationCoordinate)) {
                    ListRow(magnitude: post.properties.mag ?? 0.0, place: post.properties.place)

                }

            }
          .navigationBarTitle(Text("Today"))      
            .navigationBarItems(

                    trailing:
                    VStack {

                        Button(action: {
                            print("Edit button tapped")
                            self.showEditPage.toggle()
                        }) {
                            //Top right icon
                            Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: .center)
                        }.sheet(isPresented: $showEditPage) { 
                            return EditPage().environmentObject(self.networkManager)

                        }

                    }




            )



        }
        .onAppear {
            //Call function to fetch data
            self.networkManager.fetchData()
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works well, I can see all the data, but when I do the same thing in my second view file, I get the data back, but it does not update for the first view

**In my second editing view file: EditPage.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct EditPage: View {

    //@ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager()

    @EnvironmentObject var networkManager: NetworkManager

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("Edite")


        }
        .onAppear(){

            //I called the same function to get data as in first view file, but it is not updating the list view 
            self.networkManager.fetchData()


        }

    }
}
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        //Set up environment object
        let contentView = EarthQuakeList().environmentObject(NetworkManager())

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(
                rootView: contentView
            )
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

So I am expecting second view file to call function *self.networkManager.fetchData()* to get data from API call, then update list view in first swift file **EarthQuakeList**, the issue is I am just getting correct data back, the view is not updating with new data

Comment: Please see my code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57161893/swiftui-how-to-iterate-over-an-array-of-bindable-objects/58726705#58726705) for approach to refresh 1st view being edited in 2d. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @Asperi I am using the same way you are coded. ObservedObject and ObservableObject

Comment: As I see from your example, you don't - there is nothing that forces view to refresh. Pay attention of how refreshed State is used.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The whole issue is very easy to fix just add self.networkManager @ **EarthQuakeList.swift**

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showEditPage) { 
                            return EditPage().environmentObject(self.networkManager)
```

I got the reason and inspired from article: 
https://github.com/peterfriese/Swift-EnvironmentObject-Demo

Comment: I'm using this solution to add an environmentObject to my .sheet. However, within my .sheet, I have NavigationLinks to further views. It seems like I have to use the above solution to pass my environmentObject to every single subsequent view through the NavigationLink hierarchy, otherwise I get the No Observable Object crash. I would have thought the subsequent views from the parent .sheet would be children of the .sheet and thus inherit the Environment Object, but that does not seem to be the case. Anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: The OP's EarthQuakeList.swift is identical to that suggested in this response. Could someone backfill the question and the response so as to provide a basis for comparison? The OP's question is valueless without it.

Answer (score 4):

**`NOTE:`**`This answer was given before the question was modified to represent the next problem the developer ran into.`

This problem seems to be cause by using two instances of `NetworkManager` in your code.

If you add this line to the `NetworkManager`:

```swift
final class NetworkManager: … {

    static let shared = NetworkManager()

}
```

And then update the references in your two views like this:

```swift
struct EarthQuakeList: … {

    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager.shared

    …

}

struct EditPage: … {

    @ObservedObject var networkManager = NetworkManager.shared

    …

}
```

This will make sure both views use the exact same object to access the information. By using the same object, updates in one view will cause the other view to be updated as well.

Once this works, I recommend to play around with `.environmentObject()` ([example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)) in SwiftUI as this would allow for sharing the same instance of these service types across your application.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi @herzi , this works! Thank you so much! you are the best.

Comment: I just updated my question have ```.environmentObject()``` , but the second view is not updating the first view, and it is crashed, could you pls take a look on it?

Comment: A recommendation for the next one: Try to post a new question (and maybe link it in a comment). This way, other people can still claim an “accepted” response.

Comment: I am using this Singleton design pattern, and I am facing the problem, this didn't solve at.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using sheet ore navigation you have to pass the environment Object maybe its a bug of swiftUI but it works for me in Xcode 11.5:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $show){
        mySheetView().environmentObject(self.myEnviromentObject)
}
```

Comment: By chance where would these bugs be listed/reported? Your solution resolved it for me but I have no official place to reference this. Do you know where this might be?

Comment: SO i tried this but it still said that myEnvirontmentObject cannot be found like so: 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type IconNames found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for IconNames may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the observableObject was moved to a framework but a reference was retained in the program. One class was injected with observableObject() another one looked up by @EnvironmentObject resulting in a runtime crash OP have observed.

When moving files between the projects do be sure that you have removed the reference in the outgoing project.

Casey: to elaborate: if I remember this right there was newly a Foo in the framework namespace and there was an outgoing Foo in the program (Foo got promoted from the program to the framework but the file was not removed in the program). These were two different Foos. The outgoing Foo from the program namespace had to go opening the door to the one and the only public(open) Foo from the framework. Not only the removal of Foo file from the program fixed the crash but also removed the need for compiler to compile newly unneeded code (that got moved to the framework target).

Comment: I also moved mine to a framework, and am importing and using it from there, but getting the crash somewhere in the app. I am curious what your reference retained in the program looked like. Would you please elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant response. This was my problem exactly and the error message just sent me chasing my tail for hours trying to figure out what was wrong with my property wrapped objects (spoiler: nothing).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this in a situation where I had

```
open Base
{
}
```

that a class in my framework was relying on and
`@EnvironmentObject var base: Base` was declared

while the app had class `Derived: Base {...}`

Environment had to be reinjected like so:

```
ViewInAFramework.environmentObject(derived as Base)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think may be you have used the keyword final to the class networkManager

Trying removing the keyword and try

As final Keyword is used if we don't want to create any further instance of that class , Its's not working because you have created an instance of property wrapper EnvironmentObject

Try Without final class

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32320424)